# "Call to undefined method App\\Repositories\\UserRepository::arrayPaginator()",

Tags: php

```
public function getAll($data){
    try{
        $user_profile=DB::select("select * from va_user_profile_defn where is_deleted=0 order by user_login_id asc");
        $user_profile = json_decode(json_encode($user_profile), true);
        $user_profile = $this->arrayPaginator();

        if (is_null($user_profile))
        {
            return "failed";
        }

    }catch(Exception $e){
        return GlobalResponse::clientErrorResponse("error");
    }

    return GlobalResponse::createResponse($user_profile);

}
}
```

Comment: Well, do you have a function called arrayPaginator in UserRepository?

Comment: yeah...problem solved bro..thnx